# Application Crashes getting picture from sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard

What my application do is that it simply take image from `sdcard` and shows in a `listview`. When I select image from `sdcard` it displays correctly in `listview`, But when i select same image second time from `sdcard`, application crashes. What i want, if same image is selected second time it should give toast that image already exists. Thanks for helping

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    Bitmap image=(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    addattachmentsToListView(image);

    cursor.close();
}
```

here is logcat

```
10-16 00:53:34.432: E/dalvikvm-heap(5905): Out of memory on a 24023056-byte allocation.
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/dalvikvm(5905): Out of memory: Heap Size=61575KB, Allocated=43470KB, Limit=65536KB
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/dalvikvm(5905): Extra info: Footprint=61575KB, Allowed Footprint=61575KB, Trimmed=0KB
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=61575KB, Allocated=43470KB)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:658)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:730)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at com.example.androidufoneapp.CustomerRegistrationL0.onActivityResult(CustomerRegistrationL0.java:257)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5275)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3618)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3672)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
10-16 00:53:34.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 00:55:50.447: E/Trace(6372): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-16 00:56:08.376: E/dalvikvm-heap(6372): Out of memory on a 24023056-byte allocation.
10-16 00:56:08.376: E/dalvikvm(6372): Out of memory: Heap Size=63559KB, Allocated=44806KB, Limit=65536KB
10-16 00:56:08.376: E/dalvikvm(6372): Extra info: Footprint=63559KB, Allowed Footprint=63559KB, Trimmed=0KB
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=63559KB, Allocated=44806KB)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:658)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:730)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at com.example.androidufoneapp.CustomerRegistrationL0.onActivityResult(CustomerRegistrationL0.java:257)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5275)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3618)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3672)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
10-16 00:56:08.386: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is be sure that you are not holding on to a Bitmap and that any Bitmap that you are loading does not consume more memory than you currently have.  There are many resources in these forums that go into that and this is covered within Android.

[Loading Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

At this point it would be nice if they started to include built-in resources for retreiving imagery with those checks included (with lets say a flag in the method or something).  This issue is covered quite a bit everywhere.

Additionally, you can use a WeakReference to hold the Bitmap to be sure it is released.  If you want to be sure that you Toast later, then you'll need to keep track of the name of the image or something along those lines; database or local memory for temporary solution if that is what you are looking for.